# using OPENMP to parallelize a c++ code

Tags: c++, openmp

I hav parallelized my c++ code using openmp as below:

```
....//some code
   double S_theta = 0.0, S_x = 0.0, S_y = 0.0;
#pragma omp parallel for private(dx,dy,theta_new) reduction(+ : S_x,S_y,S_theta)
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
      {
        if (j==i) continue;
           double delta_x = x[i]-x[j],  

        for(int ky = -1; ky<= 1; ky++)
            {
            for(int kx = -1; kx<= 1; kx++)
               {

               if (r_ij_square > l0_two)
                  { 
                  double r_ij = sqrt(r_ij_square);
                  r_x_ij/= r_ij; 
                  r_y_ij/= r_ij;
                  double rdote = r_x_ij * e_x[j] + r_y_ij * e_y[j];
                  S_theta += e_dot_e * ( e_cross_e -  rdote * (e_x[i] * r_y_ij - e_y[i] * r_x_ij) ) / (r_ij_square * r_ij);
                  double S = rdote  /r_ij_square;
                  S_x += r_x_ij * S;
                  S_y += r_y_ij * S;
                  }
               }
        }

    double zeta = -eta / 2.0 ; 
    theta_new[i] += zeta + dt * dlthet;
    }
  ....//some code
```

But the result changes each time when I run it! When I remove this line

```
 #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+ : S_x,S_y,S_theta)
```

, the result is the same in different runs!
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What is `S`?  Are `S_x`, `S_y`, and `S_theta` properly initialized?

Comment: I ave added them right now @1201ProgramAlarm

Comment: Unless you missed a `}`, your indentation is very misleading. Fix that first.

Comment: your indentation is still misleading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `S` is declared outside the loop, and will be shared among all the threads running your loop.  Given how it is used, it can be declared as `double S = rdote  / r_ij_square;` inside the loop where it is used.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. Still outputs are different

Comment: @mathemamathema Looks like you have the same issue with the values at the very end: `dx[i]`, `dy[i]`, and `theta_new[i]`, since those are all within the `j` loop.

Comment: You are correct But I can not define them inside the j loop.

Comment: Maybe I could define them as private

Comment: @mathemamathema You can define local variables to act as accumulators (using the `reduction(+)`) then add them in after the `j` loop finishes.